# Batch Script for reading user input and echo output from CSV file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I want to write a script which will read the csv file and give the output(desired)

let say:

i have cloumns 
name department e_code e_id doj Designation

i have 100 entries

now i want to write script which will ask userinput for eg: type in name:

when user type name the script should read the csv file and give the output like department e_code e_id etc etc

please help.

thanks and regards

Comment: StackOverflow is not a script writing service. You should edit your question to include code you have tried and and specific issues you are experiencing: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p "name=Please enter name:" 
find "%name% file.csv
```

instead of `find`, maybe `findstr` is a better solution:

```
findstr /b "\<%name%\>"
```

`/b` returns only lines, that start with the given string,
`\<` and `\>` are word separators, so only lines, that start with the exact word are returned.

Comment: Thank You very much and i am sorry for the late reply.
it really helped me a lot. 

One more thing is i have heading in csv file so how to set it as heading so that when ever the command gives the output it should display the heading as well.

Comment: just add `<"%name%" set /p "head="` and `echo %head%` before the `find`